# Change position of stat_compare_means() in the plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this ggplot figure with `ggpubr::stat_compare_means()` function:
[image]

As you can see, the Wilcoxon test overlaps some dots on the left bar.

How can I move the text to the right?

Comment: Some reproducibl example would be helpful. But despite that, in the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpubr/versions/0.1.7/topics/stat_compare_means you can find parameters like `label.x` and `label.y` that should be used to position the label

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by @Mikolajm, you can use the `label.x` and `label.y` arguments in the `stat_compare_means()` function to position your text. 
The `label.x` argument changes the position of the text on the x-axis, and the `label.y` argument changes the position of the text on the y-axis.

For example (which logically doesn't make sense), I used the `mtcars` dataset.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggpubr)


ggboxplot(mtcars, x = "am", y = "carb",
          color = "am") +
  stat_compare_means(method = "wilcox.test",
                     label.x = 1.2, 
                     label.y = 10)
```

[image]

However, if we'll change the `label.x = 1.2` and `label.y = 10` to `label.x = 0.6` and `label.y = 6`, the graph would look like this:

```
ggboxplot(mtcars, x = "am", y = "carb",
          color = "am") +
  stat_compare_means(method = "wilcox.test",
                     label.x = 0.6, label.y = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. One last question... is there a way to center the text in the plot?

Comment: The "Wilcoxon, p = 0.74" or the legends?

Comment: The "Wilcoxon, p = 0.74", @DJV